# How to Identify product purchased or not form in app purchase in Window Store App

Tags: window, in-app-purchase

How to identify product purchased or not form in app purchase in Window Store App while processing purchase.

If user click cancel instead of buy. than how to get cancel button event.

Answer (score 0):

```
await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("...");
if (CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses["..."].IsActive) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```